# regular expression identities and NFAs

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I have these two problems about regular expressions, can you help me?

1) Prove (ab)∗a = a(ba)∗.

I already proved this using induction and the definition of the kleene star * but I want to prove it now using NFAs, I drawed the NFAs for each but they don't seem to be equal from the picture and I'm stuck there.

2) Prove 0∗(11)∗((00)∗0∗(11)∗)∗0 = (0+11+00)∗0

For this I was think of creating a NFA for each side then converting them to a DFA and prove them equal using the product automata but since each side is very big that sounds like too much word to do by hand and I was wondering if there is a faster way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We generally prefer that you ask only one question per question.  However, in this case, both of them appear to be covered by a previous question we have about proving equivalence of two regexps, so I'll mark this as a dup.  If that one doesn't answer your question, edit this question or post a new one.  FYI, we prefer that you search this site to look for related material before asking.  Also, it's usually better to ask a conceptual question (one that will be useful even to someone else who isn't looking at exactly the same exercise you're working on now).

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12624/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50505/755