# How can I prove that the accepted language of a given DFA or NFA or REGEX is equivalent to a given language

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I found this [How do I verify that a DFA is equivalent to a NFA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50505/how-do-i-verify-that-a-dfa-is-equivalent-to-a-nfa) but as it states it is not really a good question more of how can I check myself during an exam. Because as you might know to do this by hand for < 5 states is really hard to do without any mistake and I only get credit for a correct construction and not understanding that REGΣ = NEAΣ = DEAΣ

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11315/755

Answer (score 1):

Proving such a claim rigorously can be usually done with induction on word length $|w|$.